# cloudfiles simple uploading an image

Tags: php

I am using PHP and I have an image located at `image/tomato.png` relative to my PHP file.

I have managed to get a list of my cloudfile containers, so I know my rackspace authentication is working as expected.

Q: **How can I upload the image file to rackspace cloudfiles container `'phpx'` using PHP?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple cloudfiles API binding for PHP on github -> https://github.com/rackspace/php-cloudfiles

Sample usage :

```
<?php

// include the API
require('cloudfiles.php');

// cloud info
$username = ""; // username
$key = ""; // api key

// Connect to Rackspace
$auth = new CF_Authentication($username, $key);
$auth->authenticate();
$conn = new CF_Connection($auth);

// Get the container we want to use
$container = $conn->get_container('container name');

// store file information
$localfile = <filepath>;
$filename  = <filename>;

// upload file to Rackspace
$object = $container->create_object($filename);
$object->load_from_filename($localfile);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you ManseUK.  Can I ask where did you find that example from?